# Angular UI popover in table (ng-repeat). Using popover-is-open, how can I prevent all popovers to open?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I have a table where there are many popovers, using ng-repeat. The code looks like this:

```
     <td>
       <button uib-popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" popover-placement="left" popover-is-open="myPopover.isOpen" ng-click="myPopover.open()">Examples</button>
     </td>
```

In my controller I have this:

```
    $scope.myPopover = {

    isOpen: false,

    open: function open() {
        $scope.myPopover.isOpen = true;
    },

    close: function close() {
        $scope.myPopover.isOpen = false;
    }
};
```

When I now press the "Examples" button I open all the popovers in the table. How can I prevnent that and ONLY open/close the popover attached to the button I pressed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `ng-repeat` is looping `item in items track by $index`, you must change the `isOpen` property just for your `item`.

It should be something like this (I haven't got time to test it).

```
<button uib-popover-template="dynamicPopover.templateUrl" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" popover-placement="left" popover-is-open="item.isOpen" ng-click="openPopover($index)">Examples</button>
```

and then

```
function openPopover(i){
  $scope.items[i].isOpen = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am getting you correct try to put your table inside form tag and provide this code

`<form ng-submit="$event.preventDefault()">`

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're binding `popover-is-open=""` to the same property for all popovers.

Try something like `popover-is-open="isPopoverOpen" ng-click="isPopoverOpen = !isPopoverOpen"`

There you will create one variable `isPopoverOpen` per scope/per row.

Comment: That works, but I want to trigger close from inside the popover. With this code:  <button id="closePopUp" class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="myPopover.close()">Close</button>

Comment: @arg20 can you show me an example I have the same issue with popover and ng-repeater